# User information not being displayed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I have a case where I display some user information using a pipe:

`{{ author.id | user: 'name' }}`

I get the `id` from an author and, then, I use the `user` pipe to get its information stored in `/users/$uid`. Here's my pipe:

```
export class UserPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {}

  transform(uid: string, field: any): any {
    let data = {};

    let fb = this.af.database.object(`/users/${uid}`);
    fb.subscribe(res => {
      data = res;
      console.log(data[field]);
    });

    return data[field];
  }
}
```

This is working fine if the author is the current logged in user. However, the name isn't being displayed for others.

The name is printed normally in the console, however it's still not showing up in the HTML. I also double checked Firebase's security rules and it's fine. I don't get any errors in the console.

Comment: You have an asynchronous request going on, meaning you `return data[field]` before data is assigned in the call.

Comment: You could consider making this Pipe as `async` pipe, return `this.af.database.object(`/users/${uid}`)` from `Pipe` and on view then use {{ (author.id | user | async) ?.name }}

Comment: How can I watch for changes in the Pipe? Do you know why this doesn't happen when the author is logged in?

Comment: Thanks, @PankajParkar. Simple and great idea! haha

Comment: @drbishop but I'd not really think of to create dedicated `Pipe` for it. I'd rather create a observable in my component and put async pipe as I shown.. That is the reason I didn't added the answer

Comment: But is there any issues on creating a pipe? I'd have to reuse it in several components. That's why I thought of creating a pipe, so I didn't have to do that all the time.

Comment: @drbishop same could have put inside service..then use `async` pipe over it

Comment: My problem is: in this case I'm looping through a list of items (using `ngFor`), where I get the author id of each item. I didn't want to fan-out the user data, so I thought of creating a pipe. But, yeah, I think creating a service makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: This really depends on how you normally use your data. If most consumption is in the view, I would move the complexity to pipes, components, or directives. In this case you might even want to implement this in a component. -- I added a new section in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `transform()` function has used an observable. The simpliest approach is wrapping your result with an `AsyncPipe` if you want to consolidate the mapping logic into the pipe.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'user',
  pure: false
})
export class UserPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private asyncPipe: AsyncPipe;

  constructor(ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private af: AngularFire) {
    this.asyncPipe = new AsyncPipe(ref);
  }

  transform(uid: string, field: any): any {
    let fb = this.af.database.object(`/users/${uid}`).map(res => res[field]);
    return this.asyncPipe.tranform(fb);
  }
}
```

Or if you would like to implement this feature in a component, though not recommended, just for fun

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-user',
  template: '{{ result | async }}'
})
export class UserComponent {
  @Input() uid: string;
  @Input() field: string;
  result: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    let field = changes.field.currentValue;
    let uid = changes.uid.currentValue;
    if (uid && field) {
      this.result = this.af.database.object(`/users/${uid}`).map(res => res[field]);
    }
    else {
      this.result = Observable.of(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Use this with:

```
<my-user uid="12345" field="name"></my-user>
```

Or alternatively, you can just do what is suggested in the comment, just `return this.af.database.object('/users/uid')` and pipe the result with `async` pipe.